# Python - run external script

Tags: python, program-entry-point

Does someone know if I have a script `one.py` which is written the following way:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Do something
```

And I want to call that `main` function from another script. How should I do that?

I guess it would be something like *(let's say this is `launcher.py`)*

```
# 'one' stands for import from `one.py` module
import one

if __name__ == '__main__':
    one.main()
```

*The only problem is that I can't call `main()` this way.*

**How should this be done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with file('a.py','rU') as f:
  co=compile(f.read(),'foobar','exec')
  exec co in {'__name__':'__main__'}
```

Comment: This works, but it's not the _right_ way to do it. The point is that the `__name__ == '__main__'` sentinel checks whether your program is being run standalone. Sure, you can pretend that it is, but you shouldn't -- instead, you should call the API it exposes yourself! That is, you call `a.main()` from `b`.

Comment: Besides what @katrielalex says, this seems to be unnecessary complex and might not be understandable at a first glance.

Comment: I'm with katrielalex and Felix, this does what requiered but it's definitely not the way to go.

Answer (score 8):

Define your script like:

```
def main():
    # Do something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Processing of possible input parameters here and passing to main
    main()
```

Then you can do

```
# 'one' stands for import from `one.py` module
import one

if __name__ == '__main__':
    one.main()
```

Of course you can name the function however you want.