# Running Py4A script from external SD card?

Tags: android, python, sl4a

I need to run the Python script from external SD card, which in the target device is mounted as `/mnt/sdcard/_ExternalSD`.

I've succeeded to accomplish that in a quick&dirty way by preparing the "proxy" script `ExtSDRun.py` in the standard SL4A scripts directory, which in case of my target device is `/mnt/sdcard/sl4a/scripts`

```
import android
droid = android.Android()
import os
import sys
# Add directory with the scripts to the Python path
sys.path.append("/mnt/sdcard/_ExternalSD/scripts")
# Start the script located in the external SD card
# in the script_to_run.py file
import script_to_run
# You can also do:
# from script_to_run import *
```

Is there any better and more elegant way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can run a script from an external SD card. Try [this](https://gist.github.com/carlsmith/5673832). It's a simple Python function that launches any script SL4A has an installed interpreter for, given an arbitrary path to the script. I don't have an external card to test it on, but see no reason for it to fail.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: you can't. A better way to do what you're doing is to put a main function is script_to_run. i.e. if script_to_run contained this:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('Hi!\n') #Technically I should use print, but I'm trying
#to make the program longer.
```

you'd do this:

```
import sys

def main():
    sys.stdout.write('Hi!\n')
```

Then, when you import it, use:

```
import script_to_run
script_to_run.main() #This is what runs the script
```

Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4463726/2097780. I wouldn't recommend doing that, but it might be an option if you can't call main the other way.

Good luck!

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question. If you're certain it's impossible, can you explain why?

Comment: @CarlSmith: 1.The script you provided a. requires root and b. doesn't work for me. 2. He was asking on running the script from Python. The shell script would require SL4A to request root access. But the standard su binary doesn't work with SL4A, so you have to download suu(su unrestricted). And then, there's still the problem with the script not always working or requiring tweaks to the Python library files to work. In the end, you end up with a really big headache and nothing accomplished. And I should know: I went through that!

Comment: ~ I don't understand. The script I provided is Python and works on my Galaxy SII which is not rooted. Are you saying that the device must be rooted for Python to access the external card? The script I posted executes any file on my unrooted device, but I don't have an external card. I'll have a look and see if I can find a card, test it, and get back to you.

Comment: @CarlSmith: I thought you were referring to the only one I knew about at the Python for Android Google Code page. Where did you find that? I had been looking for something like that for ages, and I eventually gave up. Huh. I'll have to download that one and check it out.

Comment: @CarlSmith: The other script required root because it was accessing Python via the shell, but it kept failing with weird errors. It also required a custom su binary to call it, since Python can't call su due to uid restrictions.

Comment: No worries mate. To give credit, I got the code from another answer on SO that wasn't easy to find, then just tidied it up a bit. I spent ages trying to figure it out too.

Comment: @CarlSmith: I am going to check that out. Thanks!